# Module '"firebase/analytics"' has no exported member 'getAnalytics'

Tags: angular, firebase, google-analytics

I'm trying to connect my app with google analytics and I'm following the firebase documentation, (https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=web) but when I try to initialize firebase analytics I get Module '"firebase/analytics"' has no exported member 'getAnalytics' when I try to import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
I had firebase 7.14.0 and I updated it to the newest (7.24.0), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: That `7.24.0` seems to be latest version of AngularFire. Try `npm i firebase@latest` to install latest version of Firebase SDK. You can just follow AngularFire's documentation perhaps,

Comment: Thanks it worked, but now my firebase auth code died so i need to rewrite that.

Comment: If your code still uses namespaced syntax of V8 then yes or you could use [compat version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#example_3_combining_version_8_and_version_9_code_styles) to keep using existing code.